# How to run "youtube.com" in background in webview (android), when the activity/app is in backgound?

Tags: android, webview, youtube

How to run "youtube.com" in background in webview (android), when the activity/app is in backgound?

whenever the app is sent to background, playback stops.
how to prevent the pause?

Comment: I don't think YouTube APIs allow that.

Comment: This should not be possible on a normal way, otherwise they would ruin the own business with Youtube Premium, if a simple app would be able to play Youtube in Background